# NServiceBus and system integration: how to handle messages properly?

Tags: nservicebus

I am integrating two (and in future probably more than two) systems by using NServiceBus that utilizes MSMQ transport layer.
I need to support synchronization of several business object types (in particular Create, Update, Delete events on these objects from both endpoint sides).
I am using Pub/Sub messaging pattern.

NSB messages transport the information about Creating, Updating and Deleting business objects. Service bus should disable updating or deleting objects that do not exist in the particular endpoint system.

Let's consider the following case. There are messages published in the following order in Endpoint1:

```
[Message1]: "create business object A"
[Message2]: "update business object A"
[Message3]: "delete business object A"
```

Question 1: We do not know in which order Endpoint2 will (a) receive to inbound queue and (b) handle the above messages, am I right?

Question 2: If Message1 will not be handled correctly in Endpoint2 it will be put back in queue and other messages will be processed first, am I right?

Question 3: In that case, Message2 and Message3 will end up with error because of a try of operation on not existing object. How should I handle Message2 and Message3 then? Should I use sagas for that?

Question 4: Another problem: if there are several "update object A" messages - how to ensure/force that the last one with be handled as the last one?

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: We do not know in which order Endpoint2 will (a) receive
>   to inbound queue and (b) handle the above messages, am I right?

Correct.  That said, depending on how close together you expect these messages to be generated, it may be anywhere from very likely to very unlikely that they will be received and processed out of order.

> Question 2: If Message1 will not be handled correctly in Endpoint2 it
>   will be put back in queue and other messages will be processed first,
>   am I right?

It will be tried *x* number of times immediately based on configuration (I think the default is 5), then will fall back to Second Level Retries, which will allow other messages to be processed while this message is deferred.

> Question 3: In that case, Message2 and Message3 will end up with error
>   because of a try of operation on not existing object. How should I
>   handle Message2 and Message3 then? Should I use sagas for that?

Sagas would definitely be a possible option for this.  Is the workflow exactly create => update => delete?  Can there be multiple updates?  Does the delete always happen?  Sagas are generally for modelling a fixed/known workflow, so this may or may not be the best option depending on your specific situation.

> Question 4: Another problem: if there are several "update object A"
>   messages - how to ensure/force that the last one with be handled as
>   the last one?

The endpoint that is performing the updates and publishing them may need to put a version number on the message (for that entity instance), and the subscriber may have to ensure that  the messages get processed in sequence.  Alternately, the subscriber just may have to discard messages with a lower version number than the last one processed.  It depends on whether each update is transitional or represents a complete overwrite of state.  In any case, the subscribing endpoint will have to manage this somehow by storing the version number locally.

Bottom line, all of this is dependent on your specific situation, how you expect the messages to be published, and the consequences of a message being processed out of order.  For example, you expect that messages will be published far enough apart in 99.999% of cases that none of this will matter, I would not recommend spending a lot of effort on it.

If these are indeed rare instances, judicious use of Bus.Defer() might be enough to straighten out the message ordering.

I'm assuming you are asking this more as a general question than a specific scenario, but if you do have a specific problem you are trying to solve, I would recommend posting your specific scenario to the [Particular mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware)--the community is generally very helpful.

Comment: Ad. Question 3: the workflow is exactly create => update(s) => delete but it can stop at any point. There can be multiple updates. So in such case, will sagas be good option?

Comment: I don't think sagas are a good option in this scenario--I think what you want is a database or some other persistent data store.  It sounds more like permanent persistence than a long-running process, unless I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: You understand me well - so one of the possible solutions would be to add message version numbers (or maybe timestamps) and store locally in database pairs of BusinessObjectInstanceType&Id and TimestampOfLastSuccessfullyHandledMessage. Then if the endpoint receives a not actual message (i.e. with version less than one from the local store) exception is thrown and in result, after retries & SLR, the message is put on the error queue. Does it seem to make sense to you? Do you see any caveats in such a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Could that work?  Yes.  Is that the best solution?  Hard to say without knowing the full story.  If a version comes in that is less than the database's version, can it be ignored?  There is no point in having it retry multiple times if you already know it's going to fail repeatedly.  Again, Stack Overflow might not be the best place for a detailed solution--I'd recommend you post on the forum (the community is very helpful).